# How to save a html page modified as it is on browser?

Tags: javascript, html, database

So, the idea here is that i got a table.html file in my computer that I'd like to open and change (either via inspect or input or what it got to work), and them save it in some way.

I've tried downloading the file but it downloads the original, no matter if I use variables, inputs, or inspect.

Maybe if there was a way to change original file directly?

I don't know much PHP but using javascript/python could it be done?

Comment: You want to change it, then right click on the file and open the file in some kind of text editor. You will be able to see the HTML codes which you can modify. A HTML file is not a excel document, you cannot edit it in a browser then save it, and expect it to show your saved edits the next time round.

Comment: I feel like your question isn't explained well. Can you try to clarify what exactly you want to get?

Comment: you want to save the DOM document. Start by googling that term

Comment: If that's what you want, type in the browser's console `document.documentElement.outerHTML` and copy the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to literally save the changes of an html file modified as it is on browser, it might be possible using python and maybe other languages but I'm not an expert in them.

As far as I know, edits made on browser don't get updated to the html file itself, or even the browser's cache.

So if it's even possible, the easiest solution I can think of is a really botched and situational pyautogui scraper to get the data from table.html displayed on the browser into a text editor to change the html file itself, and then you can save the table.html with your changes made to it.